# Setting icon for the dialog created using DialogWrapper of IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have created a dialog by extending IntelliJ's "DialogWrapper". Now i want to set icon image for the created Dialog. The information about the DialogWrapper can be found [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/user_interface_components/dialog_wrapper.html). How can i set icon(at top left corner) to the dialog?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this question from the intellij's community section. I have to use "DialogWrapper.getWindow()" . You can visit this [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205435950-Setting-icon-to-the-dialog-created-using-Dialog-Wrapper). Thanks everyone for your time